# I keep getting this error for the this code incompatible type of assignment of const char to std::string

Tags: c++

```
if(gamble == "You Get A Raise"){
            int raise[]    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
            cout << "You get a "     raise[rand()%10] << " $ Raise" << endl;
            salary = salary + raise; 
}
```

Im trying to make a program that picks out a number 1-10 then adds that to your current salary

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Comparison between distinct pointer types std::string*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `<<`?

Try this:

```
int raise[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int raise_value = rand()%10;
cout << "You get a " << raise[raise_value] << " $ Raise" << endl;
salary += raise[raise_value];
```

Your string `gamble` needs to be `std::string` too:

```
std::string gamble = "You Get A Raise";
```

---

Here is a full example:

```
int salary = 1000;
std::string gamble = "You Get A Raise";
int raise[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

if (std::strcmp(gamble.c_str(),"You Get A Raise") == 0) {
// or
// if (gamble.compare("You Get A Raise") == 0) {

    int raise_value = rand()%10;
    cout << "You get a " << raise[raise_value] << " $ Raise" << endl;
    salary += raise[raise_value]; 
    cout << "New salary is $" << salary << endl;
}
```

Comment: Oops but I got another error comparision between pointer types and std::string same error but it added invalid conversion from int* to int

Comment: @MichaelWebb - and how is `gamble` defined?

Comment: I got everything down and its saying comparison between distinct pointer types std::string*

Comment: @MichaelWebb - Your string `gamble` needs to be std::string too.

Comment: And I am using using namespace std if that helps any

Comment: @MichaelWebb - no, not like that - see update (std::string gamble = "your text";

Comment: Is it because im using a string in a if statement?

Comment: @MichaelWebb - yes, should be the same type (also, don't overlook the `;` at the end of `int raise[] ... ;`)

Answer (score 0):

You actually to store the index of the raise: `rand()%10` in order to display and then apply the same raise to the salary.

```
int raise[]    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int raiseIdx = rand()%10;
cout << "You get a "  <<  raise[raiseIdx] << " $ Raise" << endl;
salary = salary + raise[raiseIdx];
```

Your `gamble` variable should be a `std::string`:

```
std::string gamble = "You Get A Raise";
```